# Android Can an application request reinstallation of its own APK? (from installation service)

Tags: android

I have an android admin which performs all admin functions on my tablet, now I need a way to update the admin application inself.  I don't really want to install yet another app to do this, however what I am finding is that there is an error when an application brings up the Android installer and passes it an APK file that is the same as the calling application, it does not show a successful install.  Is there anyway for an application to update itself with a new apk.  (Restart is OK)  It is really quite common in general to allow apps to be self updating often requiring a restart of the application?

Here is the code:

(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + apkName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                context.startActivity(intent);

Where apkName is the same application as is issuing this call?

If this cannot be done, what are my options without installing yet another admin to update the admin application?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try setting the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the Intent you fire to start the APK Installer.  When an APK is updated or reinstalled, the application must be closed which would kill any task it is running.  If the installer is running from the same task, it might be interfering.

Comment: Still says it did not install.  Could be for other reasons. It almost seems like it needs to be in another process.  Perhaps a remote process is required ....

Comment: When you invoke an activity from another application, that activity always runs in a different process even though it may appear to be in the same task.  A task in Android is simply how activities are layers and displayed on-screen, but does not reflect what processes or threads are involved.  Can you provide more code in your question above?

Comment: Thats basically all the code there is to it except the download of the apk, where I just save off a file to the sd card.  It is run in the context of an activity.  it says context.startActvivity(intent) because I pass the context of the activity into a utility class, but its thats really all I am doing. Once I run it it brings up the system installer.  I do this for another apk and it runs fine.